# CS50 pset1 Credit error in checksum calculation

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, formula, cs50

This is my first post on here so please tell me if i made any mistakes. I tried to find an answer to my question on here but i couldn't find anything fitting.

so i have a problem in my code for the 'Credit' problem set of CS50x's week 1.
In the problemset the user has to enter a creditcard number that we have to verify as either VISA, MASTERCARD or AMEX. Otherwise the output should be INVALID.

The verification should work like this:

> **4** 0 **0** 3 **6** 0 **0** 0 **0** 0 **0** 0 **0** 0 **1** 4

every second digit, starting from the second to last digit (the bold ones), is multiplied by 2 and added together.
If however the multiplied digit has 2 digits, those two digits are added seperatly like:

> 2 * 6 = 12 so twelve will be 1 + 2

after that you take the other half of the digits (without multiplying them) and add them together so in the end you have something like

> **8 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 2** = 13 (for the digits displayed in bold)

and

> 0 + 3 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 4 = 7 (for the other half of the digits)

You add both together to get **20** (which in the problem set is called the **checksum**. If the last digit of the calculated number is a **0** the card is valid and after that you just have to check some conditions to tell if its an AMEX, VISA or MASTERCARD.

Conditions for the different creditcards:

> American Express = 15 Digits, starting with 34 or 37

> VISA = 13 or 16 Digits, starting with 4

> MasterCard = 16 Digits, starting with 51, 52, 53, 54 or 55

(Sorry for the long introduction)

I tried to make a formular for this calculation but for some reason it doesn't work for all of the numbers we get to test it. I tried a lot of things to change the calculation and the conditions at the end of my code but everytime i fix one problem, another one appears and right now it feels like i thought myself into a rabbit hole so maybe i'm just too blind to see the obvious.

We only use the libraries <stdio.h> - <cs50.h> - <math.h> so far.

```
    long checkcredit = store;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2;
    for (int duo = 0; checkcredit > 0; duo++, checkcredit /= 10)
    {
        if (duo % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum1 += (checkcredit % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            sum2 = (checkcredit % 10) * 2;
            if (sum2 >10)
            {
                sum2 = (checkcredit % 10) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    sum1 +=sum2;
    sum1 = sum1 % 10;
```

This is the part in which i think the problem is since i printed out the **sum1** (the calculated verification number of the long digit) and it sometimes has the wrong output.

> **store** is the original value of the creditcard number (for example 4003600000000014)

> **checkcredit** is just a duplication of **store** to work with without changing the original store value

> **sum1** is for the number is displayed in bold (the once that get multiplied by 2 before adding)

> **sum2** is for the other half of the number

> **duo** is a digit counter for the calculation to see if i the current digit is multiplied or not *(thanks to a coworker of mine who gave the hint that i could try it that way, my old version was like 4 times longer*

in the end i just add **sum1** and **sum2** together to get the **"Checksum"**

There is no compiler error whatsoever, just the Check50 output

> Results for cs50/problems/2021/x/credit generated by check50 v3.2.2

> :) credit.c exists

> :) credit.c compiles

> **:( identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX
> expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID\n"**

> **:( identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX
> expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID\n"**

> **:( identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD
> expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "INVALID\n"**

> **:( identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD
> expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "INVALID\n"**

> **:( identifies 4111111111111111 as VISA
> expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"**

> **:( identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA
> expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"**

> :) identifies 4222222222222 as VISA

> :) identifies 1234567890 as INVALID

> :) identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID

> :) identifies 4062901840 as INVALID

> :) identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID

> :) identifies 4111111111111113 as INVALID

> :) identifies 4222222222223 as INVALID

like i said i think that the error i made is in this part of the code (i even think it has something to do with the condition in the **for** loop) but i can't figure out what is wrong there.

Just in case the whole code is here:

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Ask user for credit card number
    long store;
    do
    {
        store = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while (store < 0);

    //calculating the amount of digits 
    long cnumber = store;
    int digits;

    for (digits = 0 ; cnumber > 0 ; digits++)
    {
        cnumber/=10;
    }

    //calculating the checksum
    long checkcredit = store;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2;
    for (int duo = 0; checkcredit > 0; duo++, checkcredit /= 10)
    {
        if (duo % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum1 += (checkcredit % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            sum2 = (checkcredit % 10) * 2;
            if (sum2 >10)
            {
                sum2 = (checkcredit % 10) + 1;
            }
            //sum1 += sum2;
        }
    }
    sum1 +=sum2;
    //printf("%i ", sum1);
    sum1 = sum1 % 10;

    //conditions for varification of the card
    if (sum1 == 0)
    {
        if (digits != 13 && digits != 15 && digits != 16)
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
        else if (digits == 16 || digits == 13)
        {
            if (digits == 16 && (store >= 51e14 && store <56e14))
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
            }
            else if ((digits == 13 || digits == 16) && ((store <= 4e13 && store < 5e13)||(store >= 4e15 && store < 5e15)))
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }    
        else if (digits == 15)
        {
            if((store >= 34e13 && store < 35e13)||(store >= 37e13 && store < 38e13))
            {
                printf("AMEX\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}
```

Please ignore the conditions part at the end, i just prototyped it together to check if it works (which it does if i ignore the checksum condition)

I'm sorry for the long post and i am really thankful for everyone who takes the time to look over this and help a beginner to learn from his mistakes.

-Wannabree

Comment: In order for `sum2` to be a _sum_ you have to sum up something, as you did for `sum1` (including the initialization), and not overwrite it each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handling of `sum2` is wrong in that it does not sum up something, but overwrites `sum2` each time. A possible remedy is to initialize `int sum2 = 0;` and change

```
        {
            sum2 = (checkcredit % 10) * 2;
            if (sum2 >10)
            {
                sum2 = (checkcredit % 10) + 1;
            }
        }
```

to

```
            sum2 += "\0\2\4\6\x8\1\3\5\7\x9"[checkcredit % 10];
```